# JMS Issue on Fuse

Tags: apache-camel, jms, fuseesb

[image: 1.png] [image: 2.png]I developed a sample code to test the Topic and durable Topic on fuse and I faced an issue.

Sample code description
My sample code consists of 3 bundles, and each bundle has its own camel context, and its own route, so I have 3 routes in 3 bundles as the following:

bundle1 route : consume file from file system and send it to a queue

```
<route id="producer-route">
    <from uri="file:D://camel_test"/>
    <to uri="activemq:queue:service.queue"/>
</route>
```

bundle 2 route: consume message from the previous queue and send it to a topic

```
<route id="router-route">
    <from uri="activemq:queue:service.queue"/>
    <to uri="activemq:topic:router.topic"/>
</route>
```

bundle3 route:  consume message from the previous topic and send it to the file system

```
<route id="consumer-route">
<from uri="activemq:topic:router.topic?clientId=consumer&amp;durableSubscriptionName=bar"/>
<to uri="file:D://camel_test2"/>
```

When I put a file in the first folder "D://camel_test" , the sample code runs successfully in 95% of the cases and the file is disappeared from "D://camel_test" folder and moved to the second folder "D://camel_test2"

Issue Description
•   Sometime, 5% of the cases, the file isn’t consumed by the second route, and when checking the consumers and queues on jconsole, I find 
o   a registered consumer for the queue as shown in the attached jconsole screen shot (2.png).
o   The queue’s Enqueue count is increased while the queue’s Dequeue count is zero as shown in the attached jconsole screen shot (1.png).

•   The issue appears in many cases but the most reproducible case is after restarting Fuse ESB.

•    the issue doesn’t appear In every fuse restart, many times the sample code runs successfully without problems after fuse restart.

**Important Note: Always the issue disappears after refreshing bundle2 and bundle3.**

could you please advise?

Comment: Sounds wierd. Do you see any issues in the logs? Can you increase log level and search for oddities in this case?

Also, please verify that there is a consumer on the ActiveMQ queue in this case as well. You listed the Camel consumer but there seem to be no consumer on the actual queue. In the top window you have: `Subscriptions: javax.management.ObjectName[0]` - that should be 1 (number of consumers).